# Laravel: localhost is currently unable to handle request

Tags: laravel

After entering this URL in my browser `http://localhost/laravel-projects/public/`

```
This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500
```

I am running Laravel project on Xampp. I also tried Vagrant and Homestead installation but am getting the same error.

Comment: can you navigate to the project folder in cmd and do php artisan serve and paste the error you get

Comment: i am not getting any error

Comment: Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>

Comment: This site can’t be reached

127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: can you try using different port and see if the error still exist `php artisan serve --port=8080`

Comment: Maybe that's the actual HTML view content.

Comment: You have to enable error messages displaying, analyze the error and work from there. Otherwise, it is impossible to know what's going on in your page. Also check the error logs.

Comment: try to run this command 'php artisan serve'...

Comment: this is permission problem, read webserver logs (not laravel logs)